# Segmentation Fault with Valgrind error "Invalid read of size 4"

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind

I am trying to implement malloc from scratch in C however am getting a segmentation fault. When I put my code through Valgrind it says

```
First node at: 0x422c000
Size of free chunk: 8032
Next node at: 0x3e700000028
==350== Invalid read of size 4
==350==    at 0x1087A6: printFreeList (class_demo.c:29)
==350==    by 0x108840: test1 (class_demo.c:45)
==350==    by 0x108732: main (class_demo.c:16)
==350==  Address 0x3e700000030 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

This is the relevant function, and I can provide more information if needed. The general way the function works is by using a singly linked list to keep track of free space. Whenever I allocate space, I set a header for the allocated chunk indicating the chunk size and a magic number, then return the address of the allocated space.

```
// allocate size bytes of memory
void *my_malloc(uint32_t size){  
    // error if size is negative
    // if (size < 0) {
    //     my_errno = MYENOMEM;
    //     return NULL;
    // }
    // make sure using 8 byte aligned size 
    size = actual_size(size);
    // calculate minimum chunk size
    int minimum_chunk_size = minimum_chonk_size(size);
    // if no freelistnode create one
    if (free_list_begin() == NULL) {
        head = (FreeListNode)sbrk(8192);
        head->flink = NULL;
        head->size = 8192;
    } 
    // initialize variables
    head = free_list_begin();
    struct freelistnode * prev = NULL;
    struct freelistnode * current = head;
    void* ptr;
    // find where to allocate chunk
    while (current != NULL) {
        // large enough 
        if (current->size >= minimum_chunk_size) { 
            // set return address
            ptr = current;
            if (current->size - minimum_chunk_size >= 16) { //  allocate tail end
                // set up new freelistnode
                struct freelistnode * new = (FreeListNode)(ptr + minimum_chunk_size);
                new->size = current->size - minimum_chunk_size;
                if (prev != NULL) {
                    prev->flink = new;
                }
                new->flink = current->flink;
            } else { 
                // remove current node
                if (prev != NULL) {
                    prev->flink = current->flink;
                } else {
                    head = current->flink;
                }  
            }
            break;
        // need more space
        } else if (current->flink == NULL) { 
            if (minimum_chunk_size <= 8192) {
                // set return address
                ptr = sbrk(8192);
                if (8192 - minimum_chunk_size >= 16) { // allocate tail end
                    // set up new freelistnode
                    struct freelistnode * new = (FreeListNode)(ptr + minimum_chunk_size);
                    new->size = 8192 - minimum_chunk_size;
                    if (prev != NULL) {
                        prev->flink = new;
                    }
                    new->flink = current->flink;
                } 
            } else {
                // set return address
                ptr = sbrk(minimum_chunk_size); 
            }
            break;
        // keep going through list
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->flink;
        }
    }
    // set header
    *((uint32_t*)ptr) = minimum_chunk_size;
    *((int*)(ptr + 4)) = 999;
    // return the address
    return ptr + 8;
}
```

When I comment out the two lines in the function above:

```
// set header
*((uint32_t*)ptr) = minimum_chunk_size;
*((int*)(ptr + 4)) = 999;
```

The segmentation fault is gone. But I can't see how those two lines are causing errors.

And this is the program **class_demo.c** that calls the function

```
#include "my_malloc.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void test1();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    test1();

    return 0;
}

void printFreeList(){
    FreeListNode ptr = free_list_begin();
    printf("First node at: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("Size of free chunk: %d\n", ptr->size);
    ptr=ptr->flink;

    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("Next node at: %p\n", ptr);
        printf("Size of free chunk: %d\n", ptr->size);
        ptr = ptr->flink;
    }
}

void test1(){
    char *a = my_malloc(32);
    printFreeList();
}
```

Comment: <O/T> `if (size < 0) {` should be giving you a warning .. `size` is `unsigned`, so it's impossible for it to be < 0

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but you really ought to check the return value of `sbrk` every time you call it.  Any one of those calls could fail (returning `(void *)-1`.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Okay thanks I'll look at that now

Comment: Did you try to do as I said in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Doing address arithmetic in `void * ptr` is undefined. But that's probably not the issue.

You need to look to see why you are getting two very different addresses in your printfs. 0x422c000 and 0x3e700000028. The 0x3e700000028 value looks suspicious.

Valgrind does not work at such a low level as `sbrk`, so I would expect it to generate errors if you read or write to memory returned by `sbrk`. You should instrument your memory pool as described [here](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools).

Alternatively, rather than using `sbrk`, you could switch to using `malloc` just for testing. When your code works with `malloc`, switch back to `sbrk` (but you will still need instrumentation if you want Valgrind to produce meaningful resulults with sbrk).